# why can't I use keybinds outside the program?

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, topmost, minimized

I'm try make program to open other apps, to open this program i wan't use keybinds and for hide too.

```
        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Dark == 0)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
                {
                    if (e.Key == Key.LWin)
                    {
                        this.Topmost = true;
                        Dark = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(Dark == 1)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
                {
                    if (e.Key == Key.LWin)
                    {
                        this.Topmost = false;
                        Dark = 0;
                        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
                {
                    this.Topmost = false;
                    Dark = 0;
                    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                }
            }
```

Outside the program, keybinds do not work at all, but if the program is open, then they work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer to my class, used to global hook key event
https://github.com/nhochjkaru/JEOrbwalk/blob/master/UserActivityHook.cs

declare: `UserActivityHook actHook;`
Main function:

```
actHook = new UserActivityHook(); 
actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Window_KeyDown);
```

Comment: line 275: public event **KeyPressEventHandler** KeyPress;

Comment: line 654: MouseButtons button = **MouseButtons**.None;

Comment: 769: **Keys** keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;
770: KeyEventArgs e = new **KeyEventArgs**(keyData);

Comment: what dll i need install?

Comment: I can't comment without the error details instead of the line of error code. make sure you have changed the namespace of the class. @Darksli

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/825454011183267916/871774641092427846/devenv_nPB55jMtrH.png screenshot of errors

Comment: i fix this need add link from visual studio -.-

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms; @Darksli

Comment: can you help in discord?

Comment: if yes my discord: Darksli#8888

Comment: added u on discord